# Using Rails Serializer in an EmberJS application for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ember.js, model, serialization

I have these two models:

```
class DataSource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :deliveries
end

class DataSource::AsSubscriberSubmission < DataSource
  validates :company_id,
            :username,
            :password,
            :source_type, presence: true

  validates :source_type, inclusion: { in: ["First Party", "Third Party"] }
end
```

One is a subclass of the other, because I need to validate things in different contexts.

---

Here's how I'm using the serializer:

```
class DataSourceSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id,
             :company_id,
             :source,
             :ad_server_name,
             :source_type,
             :pinged_at,
             :status,
             :username,
             :password        
end

class DataSource::AsSubscriberSubmissionSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id,
             :company_id,
             :source,
             :ad_server_name,
             :source_type,
             :pinged_at,
             :status,
             :username,
             :password
end
```

The problem is that EmberJS is expecting this:

```
{"data_source":{"id":97,"company_id":1211,"source":null,"ad_server_name":null,"source_type":"First Party","pinged_at":null,"status":null,"username":"asdfasdf","password":"asdfasdf"}}
```

And the actual controller is giving me this:

```
{"as_subscriber_submission":{"id":97,"company_id":1211,"source":null,"ad_server_name":null,"source_type":"First Party","pinged_at":null,"status":null,"username":"asdfasdf","password":"asdfasdf"}}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the root name to the `render json` call on your controller.

Using a serializer like this:

```
class FooSerializer << ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id
```

With this call on `FoosController`

```
render json: @foo, root: 'bar'
```

Gives:

```
{"bar":{"id":1}...}
```